# Python - Calculate calculate equations with numbers on both sides

Tags: python, math, python-3.x

For a graphing calculator, I have the user input an equation, and then the program will run the equation for an x-range, asking the user for values of any variable other than x. This works fine when the equations start with `y=`.

However, I would also like to solve for equations that are a little more complex, for example `a*x**2+a*y**2+b*x+c*y+d=0`.

Is there a way to solve for something like this, where the y is not alone, or would I have to convert these equations to `y=blahblahblah`?

Comment: so you would want to find x and y from your above equation?

Comment: It would be easy to generate a raster image (at a fixed predetermined pixel resolution) from arbitrary 2D equations like this, but trickier to generate a precise line that could be saved as a vector graphic. I wouldn't know how to do the latter without (a) rearranging to have `y` terms all on one side and (b) being able to identify, and use assumptions based on, the type of function (quadratic in your example). Is a raster image good enough?

Comment: I'd suggest using a library - googling turned up http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: I second the recommendation for [Sympy](http://sympy.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not (in the general case) get a unique y=f(x) line for this.

For example x²+y²-1=0 will get you a unit circle, thus only one point to draw for x=-1, x=1, two points for any x in ]-1,1[ and 0 points for x in ]-inf,-1[ u ]1,+inf[

### Conic sections

In your case, you show the example of a second degree polynomial in two variables x and y with no mixed terms (i.e. an e*x*y in your left-hand side). Even when adding this term, if you limit the degree of the polynomial, you get a conic section, which can be a circle, ellipse, parabola or hyperbola (and degenerate cases : a point, a line, two lines, or nothing at all).

You can always express them as [image], which corresponds to the intersection between a cone and a plane, as illustrated by the following :

[image: different cases]  [image: better hyperbola]

By the way, all images/formulas come from wikipedia. As you see on the right-hand side, the hyperbola (number 3) has two disjoint parts. Number 2 shows circle and ellipse, and number 1 a Parabola.

You then need to identify in which case you are, and find a suitable parametrization to draw. Easiest to understand all of this, is to follow a course on the topic, e.g. : https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/conics_precalc

### Identifying your conic section

Luckily, the [matrix representation of a conic section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections#Classification) will tell you what kind it is.
Compute the determinant [image: matrix determinant], to check if it's non-zero. If it's zero, you have yourself a degenerate case.

Then compute the minor A33 : m = B²-4AC (which is part of the previous computation).

- If m < 0 , it is a hyperbola.

  - If A + C = 0, it is a rectangular hyperbola
- If m = 0 , it is a parabola.
- If m > 0 , it is an ellipse.

  - If A = C and B = 0 you have a circle
  - If (A+C)m > 0, the ellipse is imaginary and you cannot draw it.
- If d = 0 (degenerate case) :

  - If m < 0, you get 2 intersecting lines
  - If m = 0, you get 2 parallel lines

    - If [image: distinct real case], you get 2 distinct real lines (you can draw 2 lines)
    - If [image: coincident real case], you get 2 coincident real lines (you can draw 1 line)
    - If [image: distinct imaginary case], you get 2 distinct real lines (you can draw 0 lines)
  - If m > 0, you get a single point

You may note that quite intuitively, the degenerate circle or ellipse is a point, the degenerate hyperbola are crossing lines and the degenerate parabola are parallel lines.

### The fun barely begins

Now you're still pretty far from finished, you should still rewrite for each case your initial equation as the canonical form, which in the general case implies a changing of variables with

1. a translation
2. a rotation

From there on, you get the parametric equation and you can draw it. See [this wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Standard_form) for the list of all these canonical forms and parametrical equations (rather than copying it all). I don't think there is much point in detailing all that, it's quite long and I feel I already discouraged most readers (and if you know math you're not afraid of changing variables :) ).

The parametric equations mean that you will have a parameter (in the equations linked either t, u or theta), and that the formulas will describe the set of points of your conic section as you vary the value of that parameter.

If you feel you still want to do it all, I'd seriously advise following an online course on the topic, because this answer is quite recipe-ish and will not give you much understanding. Otherwise, use a library as recommended in the comments.